# Merge XSLTs with import/include statement using Java

Tags: java, xslt, saxon, xalan

Let's say i have two xslt A, and B. In xslt A, we have a import/include statement to use some template from B. Is there a way in Java that we generate the resulting xslt (A merged with the imported template)?? Will it be possible??

SAXON has a way to export the compiled XSLT, but unfortunately the compiled XSLT has the link to the imported XSLT, which we don't want. Any input is appreciated.

Haven't explored XALAN yet on this one.

Comment: yes! still trying with SAXON APis

Comment: You should describe your attempts some more, I up-voted (since it is a reasonable thing you ask for, I think, just in a form that deserves improvement) to undo the down-vote (not me).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use Java for this, rather than XSLT?

Most of the job is easy, it can be done with a couple of template rules:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="nested" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet | xsl:transform" mode="nested">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="nested"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:import | xsl:include" mode="#all">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)" mode="nested"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, there are complications that make it difficult or impossible if certain XSLT features have been used, for example:

- import precedences may not be converted correctly
- `xsl:apply-imports` isn't going to work
- attributes on `xsl:stylesheet` that have module scope (for example `exclude-result-prefixes`) will be lost.

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay. 
We can use XSLT also. 'll explore on this direction too.
Because of the "import precedences", i was assuming JAVA processor can help, that's why i was planning to use the Java.

Comment: The import precedence algorithm is quite tricky, but it's no more difficult to implement in XSLT than in any language (we've done it).